# Trigonometry: Find $\sin \theta$ when $\tan \theta$ is known.

Tags: trigonometry

> if $\tan \theta = \sqrt{63}$ and $\cos \theta$ is negative, find $\sin \theta$.

So since $\tan \theta$ is positive and $\cos \theta$ is negative, it lies in the $3$<sup>rd</sup> quadrant. So $\sin$ is negative, but I don't know how to find $\sin \theta$, please guide me... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Remember $\tan \theta$ is just $\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$. Here you have $\tan \theta = \frac{\sqrt{63}}{1}$ Now, draw a triangle with the sides as $\sqrt{63}$ and $1$. Now you should be able to find $\sin \theta$ and adjust the signs.

**FURTHER HINT**

> [image: A triangle]

Comment: why is cosθ = 1?

Comment: @user2463158 $\cos \theta$ is not equal to $1$. Find the hypotenuse then we have $\cos \theta = \frac{\text{adj.}}{\text{hyp.}}$ What do you get?

Comment: So hypo is 8 and answer is sin=opp/hypo=1/8 ??

Comment: Nope. Think again `:)`, you accidentally calculated $\cos$ `:)`. Look at where our reference angle is and then look at the side directly across it, which number do you get? Also, remember, $\sin \theta$ has to negative, then which one will negative? The opposite side or the hypotenuse?

Comment: so my answer is sinθ= -√63/8

Comment: YES!! Good job! and you can prove to yourself, using the answer you just found that $\tan \theta$ is equal to $\sqrt{63}$ HINT: $\cos \theta$ has to also be negative.

Answer (score 1):

In general $$\tan^2A=\frac{\sin^2A}{\cos^2A}=\sin^2A\cdot\sec^2A\iff\sin^2A=\frac{\tan^2A}{\sec^2A}=\frac{\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}$$

Comment: and if $\cos$ is negative and $\tan$ positive, $\sin$ is negative

Comment: @JohnFernley, He has already derived that

Comment: I didn't really understand what the third quadrant meant but I'll take your word for it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know by the way, you never know what could have happened if we accidentally gave a complete answer

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Because, }\tan{\theta}=\tan{(\pi+\theta)}$
$$\tan{(\pi+\theta)}=\sqrt{63}$$
$\text{Because, }\sin{(\arctan{x})}=\frac{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}$
$$\sin{(\pi+\theta)}=\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{8}$$
$$\sin{\theta}=-\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{8}$$
$\text{Note that, }\cos{(\arcsin{(-\frac{3\sqrt{7}}{8})})}\text{ could be smaller than 0. }$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan \theta = \sqrt{63} =\frac {\sqrt{63}}{1} = \frac {y-ordinate}{x-ordinate} =\frac {-\sqrt{63}}{-1}$; since it lies in the 3rd quadrant.

Then, $\sin \theta = \frac {y-ordinate}{radius} = \frac {-\sqrt{63}}{8}$

$\sqrt (x-ordinate^2 + y-ordinate^2)$ = 8  = radius, which is always positive.